# Как ждать ответ от пользователя в Telegram боте на Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

У меня есть вопрос:
Я сделал бота на библиотеке aiogram. Но надо сделать так чтобы когда пользователь нажал на кнопку "Google" то при выборе он должен принимать сообщения и поискать принятые сообщения на Google. А если пользователь нажал на кнопку "Google" то тоже самое только надо искать не в Google а на Wikipedia. Я хотел попробовать сделать с помощью `if` но бот ищет в Wikpedia кнопку которую я нажал. А сообщения которое пишу, бот осознает его как кнопку и запрос отклоняется. Я видел ответ на этом форуме ["Как ждать ответ от пользователя Aiogram Telegram Bot"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162067/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-aiogram-telegram-bot) Но на ответе было использовано класса и внутри класса хранились класса. Но я понял суть, но не мог применить. Помогите пожалуйста как это сделать

Вот код:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import wikipedia
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton
API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'
wikipedia.set_lang('en')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

wikipedia = KeyboardButton(" Wikipedia")
google = KeyboardButton(" Google")
reply_keyboard = (resize_keyboard = True, one_time_keyboard = True).add(wikipedia, google)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Welcome to Telegradroid!\nThis bot can do anything. Type /help for more", reply_markup = reply_keyboard)

@dp.message_handler()
async def wiki(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == " Wikipedia":
    await message.answer("Current search system: Wikipedia")
        try:
            await message.answer(wikipedia.summary(message.text))
        except:
            await message.answer("Resource not found")
    elif message.text == " Google":
        await message.answer("Current search system: Google")
    else:
        await message.answer("Invalid request")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Как не получается применить FSM? Ошибка какая-то?

Comment: Нет без ошибок. Просто логика не правильная

Comment: А код, который использовали у себя можете показать? (*без токена*)

Comment: Проблема как я понял не в ошибке, а в отсутствии минимально понимания того что нужно делать. В таком случае вопрос бесполезен, так как он не содержит ничего конкретного да и вы сами указали решение своей проблемы, разжевать и положить в рот у людей нет ни желания ни времени. Ознакомьтесь с обучающим материалом по данной теме и попробуйте правильно осознать ответ на ваш вопрос. https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/fsm/

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться кнопкой "Wikipedia". Не получиться